# Get row from TensorFlow tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to define a custom layer in TensorFlow but I am struggling with the data processing. As I understood it the most common way is to compute the output for a batch of inputs. This means that if the input tensor is called `input`, `input[n]` is the `n`-th training input of the batch.

Now let's assume that each example consists of two vectors `a` and `b` which are to be treated differently. For example if one training example is `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`, `a=[1,2,3]` and `b=[4,5,6]`.

Input, however, consists of many such examples, so it could be for example

```
[
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
    [[10, 27, 3],[4, 45, 61]]
]
```

*Is there a way to select a specific "row"?*

You can select an example with `input[n]`, but I want to get a tensor which us a list of all vectors `a` or all vectors `b`. The result of the example above would be `[[1,2,3],[10,27,13]]` if you want to select the vectors `a`.

Is there alternatively a way to define the operation for a single training example and make TensorFlow execute it on all examples of the batch in an efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for a lambda layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[10, 27, 3],[4, 45, 61]]]

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor) 

times_2_times_3 = lambda x: (tf.multiply(x[0], 2), tf.multiply(x[1], 3))

layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(times_2_times_3)

layer(next(iter(ds)))
```

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([2, 4, 6])>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([12, 15, 18])>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it. I was looking for the slicing operator. Given the input

```
x=[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
[[10, 27, 3],[4, 45, 61]]]
```

you can get the tens`[[1,2,3],[10,27,13]]` by running
`result=x[:,0]`
which means selecting all elements from the 0th dimension (the "batch dimension") and the first element from the 1st dimension.
I am afraid the lambda layer solution only works for a single training example.